# Sending extra params from angular application to keycloak

Tags: angular, keycloak

I am using angular as a front-end application and want to send some extra parameters to use. I am unable to find any relevant documentation for this.  I have tried sending something in acr key but doesn't work well. Here is the sample code I am using.

```
// initialization of keycloak instance
this._keycloakInstance.init({
        config: {
            url: domain,
            realm: realm,
            clientId: client,
        },
        initOptions: {
        },
    });
// At the time of login
// How could I pass extra Params over here?? e.g. tempId: 'abc'
this._keycloakInstance.login({redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',scope :  'openid'}
```

and in which particular key I could get that. I am using script mapper in the keycloak.
Directly from postman I could add a param in x-www-form-urlencoded and can access this variable while getting token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle passing variables, you can add them to the redirect URL. To ensure success, all you need to do is encode the redirect URL along with its parameters.

example

```
http://localhost:8182/realms/keycloak-angular-sandbox/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=keycloak-angular&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%3Fx%3D7&state=db6a1512-976f-4707-9733-68a84810c036&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=bbfb2bef-2fe6-49b3-8f64-0003378c5c96
```

```
encoded redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%3Fx%3D7
decoded redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200?x=7
```

and in keyclock admin dashboard, under client> your client name add `/*` at the end of valid redirect url